# C# захват буфера обмена Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, clipboard, хук

Задача:

- Слушать буфер обмена
- При копировании пользователем информации в другом окне, запоминать ее
- Определять чем она является
- Работать с ней, если она - текст

Условия:

- Консольное приложение на C#
- Программа свернута (не находится в фокусе)

Реализации которые я видел используют WinApi, вот один пример из таких реализаций:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndDel, IntPtr hWndNext);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam1, IntPtr lparam);

        IntPtr hWndNextWnd; //Для хранения указателя на следующее окно

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) // переопределяем метод 
        {
            switch (m.Msg) //Анализируем сообщение Windows
            {
                case (0x0001): // Код WM_CREATE наше окно создано
                    hWndNextWnd = SetClipboardViewer(this.Handle); // Помещаем наше окно в цепочку и сохраняем указатель на следующее 
                    break;
                case (0x0002): // Код WM_DESTROY окно будет разрушено, нужно удалитmся из цепочки буфера обмена
                    ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, hWndNextWnd); // Удаляем наше окно и передаём указатель на следующее окно
                    break;
                case (0x030D): // Код WM_CHANGECBCHAIN одно из окон удаено из цепочки, нужно востоновить цепочку
                    if (m.WParam == hWndNextWnd) // Если удаляемое окно это следующие окно в цепочке
                        hWndNextWnd = m.LParam; //Следующим окном делаем окно идущее в цепочке за удаляемым 
                    else if (hWndNextWnd != IntPtr.Zero) // Если дескриптор следующего окна определён
                        SendMessage(hWndNextWnd, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);// Посылаем сообщение этому окну
                    break;
                case (0x0308): //Код WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD содержимое буфера изменилось можно работать
                {
                    //НА МЕСТЕ ЭТОГО КОММЕНТАРИЯ ПИШИТЕ СВОЙ КОД
                    SendMessage(hWndNextWnd, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);// Посылаем сообщение о изменении бефера дальше по цепочке
                }
                    break;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m); //обращаемся к нашему методу
```

**Вопрос:** Как реализовать такое без WinForm(как в данном примере)?

Т.Е. что делать если у меня консоль и мне негде переопределять метод WndProc?

Comment: Лучше б таких программ не было... Вирус пишите?

Comment: Хочу сделать програмку, запоминающую последнии пару копированей, чтоб как в телефоне можно было скопировать несколько раз, а пото вставлять из истории.

Comment: Я делал менеджер буфера обмена с использованием таймера. Просто по таймеру делается опрос содержимого: если оно нужного типа - выполняются действия.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можно и так, но выглядит оно более кастыльно при наличии winapi

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, тоже вариант, но есть одно но. С проверкой по WM_TIMER встает та же проблема отсутствия окна. Использовать `waitable timer' мороки будет еще больше, чем с созданием окна, там точно нужен будет отдельный поток со всеми вытекающими. Есть еще некое 'Timer API', но оно основано на COM и завязано на Internet Explorer, непонятно насколько просто будет его использовать. В общем, создание окна выглядит наиболее перспективным вариантом. Разве что вы знаете еще что-то о таймерах, тогда ответьте поподробнее.

Comment: @freim - я имею в виду обычные дотнетные таймеры, скажем, `System.Timers.Timer` или `System.Threading.Timer`.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, да, так будет проще. Я пожалуй, удалю ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Совсем без WinForms такое проделать будет затруднительно. Но кто вам мешает использовать Windows Forms в консольном приложении?

Достаточно подключить библиотеку System.Windows.Forms.dll и написать что-то вроде вот такого

```
using (var handler = new ClipboardHandler())
{
    handler.CreateControl();
    Application.Run();
}
```

Только не забудьте про STAThread. Если же вам нужен способ прервать цикл обработки сообщений - можно воспользоваться CancellationToken:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

// ...

using (var handler = new ClipboardHandler())
{
    handler.CreateControl();

    using (cts.Token.Register(Application.ExitThread, useSynchronizationContext: true))
        Application.Run();
}
```

Например, можно настроить правильную остановку при нажатии Ctrl+C или Ctrl+Break:

```
Console.CancelKeyPress += (o, e) =>
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    cts.Cancel();
};
```

К сожалению, закрытие консольного окна так просто не перехватывается.